# Timed account access (PHP/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am trying to implement a demo account in one of my php webapps.

The concept is, that the user would have a total of x hours (max) access to the application since his first login. I am thinking of a frontend counter (javascript) that would begin from the first login and if the user quits the browser it will update the remaining hours on the database (before closing).

I wonder if there is a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: So you are aiming to implement X hours of actual usage and not x hours of access? That's a major difference and really a lot harder to implement right.

Comment: You cannot know when the user quits their browser. They might lose net access, or have a power outage, or their browser might crash without firing `onunload` events. This is not reliable enough for a commercial service (I assume since you're metering access, you're going to want to charge your users).

Comment: Great comment @lanzz, it's what I've been thinking after my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much is it important for you to stop potential misuse.

This way I could create the demo account and, before exiting your page, turn off js, so update never happens and I have my everlasting demo account :)

I would go with updating the time on every page and checking if number of free hours is used.

Comment: Actually you and symcbean gave me a small idea of something in between.

Answer (score 1):

Most people wouldn't implement access control using javascript - it's too easy to circumvent. If it were me, I'd implement it in the session management layer - the code is called automatically every time the user acceses a page, and, since it controls access to the sesion data anyway, it's trivial to add additional constraints.